# How to use TextMate 2's Find "In" Regular Expressions?

Tags: search, regex, find-and-replace, textmate, syntax

Ok, here is a scenario, *in pictures*.

[image: 1]

OK, so searching all files looks in 333 files, and finds 614 matches. First result is `alex/init.zsh`. Fine.

[image: less scope]

So I try to limit the scope a bit, with my logical regex of `[^alex/init*]*`.  Great. Got fewer results, fewer files were searched, 1st result is different.  Fine.

*Wanting* to eliminate all results in that `alex` directory.. I foolishly think that by *just simplifying* the regex that **worked** to `[^alex/*]*`, that ALL results that match tat expression will disappear.  **Wrong.**

[image: ugh]

Instead of matching (or shall I say EXCLUDING) MORE files, it goes back to matching (excluding) NONE! This is the most simple example of frustrating results from this search interface... trust me I could show more!

Putting this question out there... in hopes that a solution to this *simple problem* will enlighten me to the correct syntax for more advanced searches!

Comment: I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5845101/1509809) answer while googling for `textmate2 find exclude directory`. That answer provide a way to add exclude directory from textmate's settings.

Comment: @ZackTitan that's a little drastic. This is just for one-off searches.  I just need to figure out Textmate's quirky regex for this.. Or maybe it's just a bug...

Comment: Oh, you want to eleminate the results which **does not starts with Alex**? Then it is your regex problem. Your regex is matching for strings starting with the text `alex`. Your regex should be **Not starting with**. So your `[^alex/*]*` would be something like `![^alex/*]*`. Be advised you might have to adjust the regex a bit, since I'm not regex expert. I have only used regex in python and I do not know how textmate handle regex